# how to properly containerize and maintain application that require a setup wizard with Docker?

Tags: docker

If I wanted to create a simple container with e.g. an apache server, I could create a simple Dockerfile that uses an existing image, installs apache using the package manager (e.g. apt), adds the server configuration file to the image and I'm ready. Whenever either apache or the base image is updates, I can just drop the container, rebuild it and have an updated container.

This works well with easily-installable applications. But what about applications that require a complex setup-wizard to run?

- What is a good approach to create images that require some manual setup steps? Should I use a Dockerfile for the base image, run the setup and then commit into a new image?
- Can I update the application and the base system independently of each other? Consider for example a security update for the Linux base system. Can I somehow just upgrade the base image without having to reinstall the application (using the wizard)?

Comment: `Should I use a Dockerfile for the base image, run the setup and then commit into a new image?Should I use a Dockerfile for the base image, run the setup and then commit into a new image?` That sounds reasonable, I did it recently. If you look at https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ambakshi/wine-x11-vcpython27/ you see `I tried to automate this via the Dockerfile or on first login, but...`

Comment: The link in my previous comment is not mine, it is just another example.

Comment: @user2915097 thank you, it seems there really is no better solution (or is there). Do you have any hints for the second question as well (how to maintain it independently of the base image, if somehow possible)?